# Passing JSON data into div one at a time with JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, parsing, model-view-controller

I've sorted JSON data by month in an array. This is the output, populated with sample data:

```
[{"Title":"A Sample Title","Description":"<p>with sample descriptions</p>","DatePublished":"2018-08-15 01:42:10 GMT"},
{"Title":"post 2","Description":"<p>Sample post 2</p>","DatePublished":"2018-08-11 21:58:50 GMT"},
{"Title":"post 1","Description":"<p>Sample post 1</p>","DatePublished":"2018-08-11 21:57:58 GMT"}]
```

Here is some of the code:

```
var blogList = $('#blog-list');
var blogEntry = $('#blog-entry')

        //...
        var monthblogList = $('<div class = "month"> </div>').appendTo(blogList);

        $.each(inner, function(i, o) {

          title = inner[i].Title
          description = inner[i].Description
          date = inner[i].DatePublished

          $('<div class = "title-list" data-description="'+ description  +'"><h3 class = "unique-title">' + title + '</h3></div>').appendTo(monthblogList)

        })

    function showBlogPost(element){
      var d = $(element).data('description')
      $(d).appendTo('body')
    }

    $(blogList).on('click', '.title-list', function(event) {
      showBlogPost(event.currentTarget) 
    })
```

I want to be able to show **one** blog post at a time (including title, description and post date) inside the `#blog-entry` div, depending on the title that is clicked.

Right now I have it where the respective description is grabbed and printed, but it keeps printing over and over each time it's clicked. This method I'm trying to do may be completely wrong. I've tried several methods, like toggling and showing divs, but had no luck. Please explain how to do this, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't see your full code, I cannot assure this will work.

1. Make sure that you empty the contents of `#blog-entry` first.
2. Add new contents to `#blog-entry` rather than to `body`.

   ```
   function showBlogPost(element){
      blogEntry.empty();
      var d = $(element).data('description')
      $(d).appendTo(blogEntry);
   }
   ```

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution. Thank you!